# Add header to SOAP message

Tags: java, web-services, soap, java-web-start

I need add custom soap header, like login
I do it in way like this

```
class Foo implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {
    public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        try {
            SOAPMessage soapMsg = context.getMessage();
            SOAPEnvelope soapEnv = soapMsg.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
            soapEnv.addHeader().addAttribute(new QName("login"), "bob");

            soapMsg.writeTo(System.out);//tracing OUT
            return true;
        } catch (SOAPException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}

@HandlerChain(file="handler-chain.xml")//I describe Foo in this file
public class GreeterService
```

By `tracing out` I get message

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><S:Header login="bob"/><S:Body><ns2:sayGoodbye xmlns:ns2="http://example.com/"><arg0>SOAP</arg0></ns2:sayGoodbye></S:Body></S:Envelope>
```

with header

```
 <S:Header login="bob"/>
```

But server received it without any header

```
 <?xml version="1.0" ?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><S:Body><ns2:sayGoodbye xmlns:ns2="http://example.com/"><arg0 xmlns="">SOAP</arg0></ns2:sayGoodbye></S:Body></S:Envelope>
```

What I make wrong?

Comment: Is it generated code by wsimport ?

Comment: @StKiller, correct. I add SOAPHandler only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the similar issue few days ago, there was a need to send user id by header.

I resolved this problem with special parameter - `wsimport -XadditionalHeaders`  when generating code.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is not any effect of this option. It still generates same classes.

Comment: Ok, but the source wsdl contains definitions for headers ?

Comment: There is one point that I should say. Actually, there is not any information about header in wsdl. It's kind of optional header, and I handle it my myself.

Comment: I accept this answer because as it provides useful relevant information. But if you know how solve issue with optional headers, please, let me know.

Comment: @AndreiPodoprigora: I can't seem to find any documentation for this special parameter. Do you have any references?

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: Please read this topic : http://www.java.net/node/672712. Seems that is depends on wsimport version. I have version "JAX-WS RI 2.1.6 in JDK 6" and it does contain such option.

Comment: This helped me a lot, even IDEs with wsdl-2-java generation feature do not give this as an option. Thanks.